# List of functions generated using list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The following Python program prints 13 and not 7.

```
increment_by_i = [lambda x: x+i for i in range(10)]
print(increment_by_i[3](4))
```

I don't understand the following explanation given:

> This is because the functions created in the loop have the same scope. They use the same variable name, and hence, consequently, all refer to the same variable i, which is 9 at the end of the loop.

1. How does the list comprehension create the respective function in the list? In particular, how is it different from the following code of generating `increment_by_i`?

```
increment_by_i_modify=[]
for i in range(10): 
    increment_by_i_modify.append(lambda x: x+i)
print(increment_by_i_modify[3](4))
```

2. I don't understand the statement "They use the same variable name, and hence, consequently, all refer to the same variable `i`, which is 9 at the end of the loop." 
   If I write

```
test=[i for i in range(10)]
```

`test[3]` is 3 and not 9.

Comment: I think you have typo in your code ^^ change `increment_by_i = [lambda x: x+1 for i in range(10)]` to `increment_by_i = [lambda x: x+i for i in range(10)]`

Comment: List comprehension has it own scope, the funcutions are in that scope, and x is 9 when the functio LC ends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your equivalent code to your initial list comprehension has the same behavior/output
 if you test you will see that  `print(increment_by_i_modify[3](4))` has the same output, 13

your functions are not keeping the value of `i` but a reference to `i`, maybe the following code will help:

```
def get_functions():

    increment = 0 
    variables = {'i': increment}

    my_functions = []

    def create_function():
        def f(x):
            return x + variables['i'] 

        return f

    while increment < 10:
        my_functions.append(create_function())
        variables['i'] = increment
        increment += 1

    return my_functions

increment_by_i = get_functions()
print(increment_by_i_modify[3](4))
```

output:

```
13
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good explanation here: https://realpython.com/python-lambda/ (section Evaluation Time)

Adapting a little bit that explanation turns out:

The unexpected result occurs because the free variable 'i', as implemented, is bound at the execution time of the lambda expression. The Python lambda function is a closure that captures 'i', a free variable bound at runtime. At runtime, while invoking the function increment_by_i, the value of 'i' is nine.